# MediatR issue in DependencyInjectionConfig with Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, mediatr

I am using in my project MediatR. This is what I have in my service class:

```
public class WebShopServices : IWebShopServices
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public WebShopServices(IMediator mediator)
    {
         _mediator = mediator;
    }
    public void UpdateCustomerAddress(UpdateAddressInformationCommand updateAddressInformation)
        {
            _mediator.Send(updateAddressInformation);
        }
}
```

This is my handler

```
public class UpdateCustomerAddressHandler : RequestHandler<UpdateAddressInformationCommand>
{
    private readonly OnlineSalesService _client;
    private readonly IDataContractsFactory _factory;
    private readonly IParameterValidator _validator;

    public UpdateCustomerAddressHandler(OnlineSalesService client, 
        IDataContractsFactory factory, IParameterValidator validator)
    {
        _client = client;
        _factory = factory;
        _validator = validator;
    }

    protected override void HandleCore(
        UpdateAddressInformationCommand updateAddressInformation)
    {
        _validator.Validate(updateAddressInformation);

        var updateAddressCommand = 
            _factory.CreateCustomerDefaultAddressCommand(updateAddressInformation);

        try
        {
            _client.SetCustomerDefaultAddress(updateAddressCommand);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new CustomerException("Something happened with the service.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my model class:

```
public class UpdateAddressInformationCommand : IRequest
{
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }

    public AddressInformation AddressInformation { get; set; }
}
```

And this is what I wrote in dependency injection config:

```
builder.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof (IMediator).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof (Ping).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterInstance(Console.Out).As<TextWriter>();
builder.Register<SingleInstanceFactory>(ctx => {
    var c = ctx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
    return t => c.Resolve(t);
});
builder.Register<MultiInstanceFactory>(ctx => {
    var c = ctx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
    return t => (IEnumerable<object>)c.Resolve(typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(t));
});

builder.RegisterType<GetCustomerDetailsResultHandler>()
    .As<IRequestHandler<GetCustomerDetailsQuery,GetCustomerDetailsResult>>();
builder.RegisterType<UpdateCustomerAddressHandler>()
    .As<RequestHandler<UpdateAddressInformationCommand>>();
```

And it keeps giving me this exception:

> {"The requested service
>   'MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[[Service.DataContracts.UpdateAddressInformationCommand,
>   Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null],[MediatR.Unit, MediatR, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has not been registered. To
>   avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the
>   service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use
>   the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency."}

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is Ping in the same assembly as UpdateAddressInformationCommand?

Comment: Try adding this after your builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Ping).... line in your DI Config: builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).AsImplementedInterfaces();

Comment: I have the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating an empty class UpdateAddressInformationResult, and in UpdateCustomerAddressHandler I implemented interface IRequestHandler.
I really don't know how to solve the RequestHandler issue. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to registering IRequestHandler via:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).As(t => t.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(i => i.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>)))
            .Select(i => new KeyedService(HandlerKey, i)));
```

To make it easier to use mediatr and Autofac try the MediatR.Extensions https://github.com/bernos/MediatR.Extensions

Comment: What are you passing as 
assembly?